# Problems with the sockets work when proxy nginx on sub location

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Problems with the sockets work when proxy nginx on sub location.

Deploy a sample application from the official documentation 
https://github.com/chrismccord/phoenix_chat_example

further configure the Nginx

```
server {  
 listen 4200;  
 server_name phoenix_chat_example;  

 access_log /var/log/nginx/phoenix_chat_example.access.log;  
 error_log /var/log/nginx/phoenix_chat_example.error.log;  

 charset utf8;  

 location ^~ / {         
  proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;    

  proxy_http_version 1.1;  
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;    
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;  
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;  
 }  
}
```

then add an option (check_origin: false) in the config phoenix_chat_example/config/dev.exs

```
config :chat, Chat.Endpoint,
  http: [port: System.get_env("PORT") || 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  cache_static_lookup: false,
  check_origin: false,
  code_reloader: true,
  watchers: [node: ["node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch", "watch"]]
```

We go to http://phoenix_chat_example:4200/, and see that everything works

Now change location in the configuration nginx

> location ^~ /chat_application {    .....

and change the path to the static resources

> "/css/app.css" -> "/chat_application/css/app.css" "/js/app.js" ->
>   "/chat_application/js/app.js"

in phoenix_chat_example/web/templates/layout/app.html.eex

and change socket url in phoenix_chat_example/web/static/js/app.js

> new Socket("/socket" -> new Socket("/chat_application/socket"

and we see an error

> phoenix.js:644 WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://phoenix_chat_example:4200/chat_application/socket/websocket?user_id=123'
>   failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code:
>   404

on client-side

and

> [info] GET //socket/websocket [warn] ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError)
>   no route found for GET /socket/websocket (Chat.Router)
>       (chat) web/router.ex:1: Chat.Router.match_route/4
>       (chat) web/router.ex:1: Chat.Router.do_call/2
>       (chat) lib/chat/endpoint.ex:1: Chat.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
>       (chat) lib/plug/debugger.ex:93: Chat.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
>       (chat) lib/phoenix/endpoint/render_errors.ex:34: Chat.Endpoint.call/2
>       (plug) lib/plug/adapters/cowboy/handler.ex:15: Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Handler.upgrade/4
>       (cowboy) src/cowboy_protocol.erl:442: :cowboy_protocol.execute/4

on backend-side